# Change disabled true/false textfield according to the value of TWO dropdowns

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#estado').change(function() {
            if( $(this).val() == 'Todos') {
                $('#busquedatext').prop( "disabled", false );
            } else {       
                $('#busquedatext').prop( "disabled", true );
            }
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

This change a textfield (busquedatext) only if Todos is selected in the dropdown "estado". The thing is I have two dropdowns ("estado" and "anio") and want to enable/disable the textfield ony if "Todos" is selected in both of them.

How can I do this?

Edit:

As per patstuart I added this:

```
    $('#estado, #anio').change(function() {
```

But with this, I can have Todo and XXX and the textfield is enabled.

Comment: I found a solution :)
$(document).ready(function() {
 
   $('#estado, #anio').change(function() {

    if ($("#estado").val() == "Todos" && $("#anio").val() == "Todos"){    
         $('#busquedatext').prop( "disabled", false );
    } else {       
      $('#busquedatext').prop( "disabled", true );
    }
  });
 
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener to both fields.

Try this:

```
    $('#estado,#anio').change(function() {
         $('#busquedatext').prop( "disabled", $('#estado') === "Todos" && $('#anio') === "Todos");
    });
```

Comment: Hello, I really don´t understand :(. I added the listener but then with the second line the script didn´t work.  I don´t know how to work with the "$('#busquedatext').prop( "disabled", $('#estado') === "Todos" && $('#anio') === "Todos");" you proposed :/ Where is the if?

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` in the test. You also don't need `if`, just use the result of the test as the second argument to `.prop()`.

```
$("#busquedateext").prop("disabled", $("#estado").val() == 'Todos' && $("#anio").val() == "Todos");
```